# SQL - adding space to a string

Tags: sql, database, oracle, whitespace, analysis

I'm looking for a solution that would insert space after specific CODE sign appears in the entire string under DESCR attribute field.

Available data sample:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfWE1.png)

The overall logic is that SQL assigns specific CODE when it finds it with CASE else it assigns static, default CODE.

The CODEs are as follow: VBN, BNM, XCV. Random as I want to show that each single one has different length and letters pattern.

```
SELECT FUND_FAMILY,BUSINESS_UNIT_AP,VOUCHER_ID,INVOICE_ID, VENDOR_ID, DESCR
 FROM
 (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as RowNumb, FUND_FAMILY,BUSINESS_UNIT_AP,VOUCHER_ID,INVOICE_ID, VENDOR_ID, DESCR
     FROM (

SELECT FUND_FAMILY||BUSINESS_UNIT_AP||VOUCHER_ID||INVOICE_ID||VENDOR_ID ID,FUND_FAMILY,BUSINESS_UNIT_AP,VOUCHER_ID,INVOICE_ID, VENDOR_ID, 

DESCR FROM (
SELECT
VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
     CASE instr (DESCR, 'XCV') 
     WHEN  (0) 

     THEN (CASE instr (DESCR, 'VBN') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'BNM') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'ASD') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'ERT') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'ERY') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'RTTYUU') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'HJKKK') 
     WHEN  (0)

     THEN  'CODE2'  

     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE8'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE7'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE6'), 4) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE5'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE4'), 5) END)   
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE3'), 4) END)  
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE2'), 6) END)  

     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE1'), 4) 

     END AS FUND_FAMILY,

BUSINESS_UNIT_AP,VOUCHER_ID,INVOICE_ID,VENDOR_ID, DESCR FROM TABLE_NAME 

WHERE UNIT IN ('ETITY1')
AND ACCOUNT = '135000' 
AND FISCAL_YEAR > 2013

AND (DESCR LIKE '%CODE1%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE2%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE3%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE4%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE5%'
OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE6%' OR  DESCR LIKE '%CODE7%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE8%' OR DESCR LIKE '%CODE9%')

AND NOT DESCR LIKE '%CODE10%'

GROUP BY 
VOUCHER_LINE_NUM , 
     CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE1') 
     WHEN  (0) 

     THEN (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE2') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE3') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE4') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE5') 
     WHEN  (0) 
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE6') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE7') 
     WHEN  (0)
     THEN  (CASE instr (DESCR, 'CODE8') 
     WHEN  (0)

     THEN  'CODE2'  

     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE8'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE7'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE6'), 4) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE5'), 5) END)
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE4'), 5) END)   
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE3'), 4) END)  
     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE2'), 6) END)

     ELSE  SUBSTR(DESCR, instr (DESCR, 'CODE1'), 4) 
     END, BUSINESS_UNIT_AP,VOUCHER_ID,INVOICE_ID,VENDOR_ID, DESCR


    )
        )
            ) X 
WHERE RowNumb = 1
```

Comment: Do these codes match a pattern, or are they looked up from somewhere? In your example `7/13 SICAVFT-BNMAPPL GERMAN`, why do you pick `BNM` as the code and not `VFT` or `PPL`?

Comment: These codes don't follow pattern - they are distinct. VBN, BM etc are only a coding example to show that they differ from each other in letters and length.

Comment: Original codes I want to distinct with spaces are: FGIF, FTIF, FTOF, FTSF, FTSIF, FTSIIF, FTSMF , TISCE

Comment: Not VBN, BNM or XCV as in your question? The regex for the latest list is `(FGIF|FTIF|FTOF|FTSF|FTSIF|FTSIIF|FTSMF|TISCE)`.

Comment: VBN, BNM were made up to show the lack of pattern in the naming.

Comment: regexp_replace    (descr, '(FGIF|FTIF|FTOF|FTSF|FTSIF|FTSIIF|FTSMF|TISCE)(.)', '\1 \2', 1)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I think it's working! Will do some testing and let you know!

Comment: See updated answer below - refined a bit to take care of existing spaces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`regexp_replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm).

```
trim(regexp_replace(descr,'( )*(FGIF|FTIF|FTOF|FTSF|FTSIF|FTSIIF|FTSMF|TISCE)( )*',' \2 '))
```

The regex looks for `[zero or more spaces][any one of your codes][zero or more spaces]` and replaces it with `[ ][the code it found][ ]`. The `trim()` is needed in case the code appears at the start or end of a string. (I expect there is a way to handle this within the regex itself, but just `trim`ing the whole expression is a heck of a lot easier.)

Comment: The tricky part is that CODE actually looks different per row... TIG, TIGF, TIGI etc

Comment: I also tested it and it returns 'FGIF8 ' rather then 'FGIF 8'

Comment: So `CODEn` is not a string pattern but a value in some other column? I guess I missed that detail in your question ;)

Comment: Instead of CODE I get various stirng values like: FTIFXXX-AAA, FTIG XXX-AAA, FTTMS-XXX-AAA, FTTMS XXX-AAA etc ;)